# How to retrieve the WeekofMonth for a given date in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a date field in Hive 2018-06-10, from which i need to get WeekOfMonth

```
WEEKOFYEAR(order_time)
```

I need output for 2018-06-10 as 3 (which is 3rd week. assuming week starts from Sunday)

Is there any built in function in Hive to retrieve WeekofMonth. I couldn't find any. I tried below to convert based on minutes and seconds but

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE())+7200)
```

But the above is not giving correct value

Comment: How is 10th 3rd week?

Answer (score 1):

For the week of the month, you can get the day part of the month and divide by 7.

```
select case 
  when DAYOFMONTH(order_time)%7 = 0  
       then DAYOFMONTH(order_time)/7 
       else DAYOFMONTH(order_time)/7 + 1 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [date_format](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) function:

```
select date_format('2018-06-10','W');
```

See more format patterns here: [SimpleDateFormat](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'm trying to get the week of month out of a timestamp with date_format(dt_col, 'W') but it defaults to starting the week on Sunday, is there any way to change this to start on Monday instead? Im on spark 2.4